# Wrong or corrupted displayed images using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm setting a web application where I need to display some images. This images i receive from API that turns matplotlib diagram into png and then with io library send it to main web application. So images that i show on page almost always shown as incorrect or wrong. But if i open them in a new page by context menu they're ok.
[image: corrupted images]

so this piece of code that send diagram

```
@app.route('/send-data-a', methods=['GET'])
def send_data_user_dynamic():
...some code for diagram...
image_stream1 = io.BytesIO()
        plt.savefig(image_stream1, format='png')
        image_stream1.seek(0)
        plt.close(fig)

        return send_file(image_stream1, mimetype='image/png')
```

I've tried to put timestamps in main application, so links would be unique but, it doesn't help

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def data():
    timestamp = int(time.time())

    user_dynamic = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-a?timestamp={timestamp}')
    user_amount = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-b?timestamp={timestamp}')
    kp_month = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-c?timestamp={timestamp}')
    kp_week = requests.get(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-d?timestamp={timestamp}')

    return render_template('second.html',
                           user_dynamic=user_dynamic.url,
                           user_amount=user_amount.url,
                           kp_month=kp_month.url,
                           kp_week=kp_week.url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

and there is a html template that output them

```
    <div class="diagram">
        <img src="{{ user_dynamic }}" alt="user_dynamic">
        <figcaption>some text</figcaption>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing... I'm sending images from a tarfile.extract_file, which is a BytesIO. Trying to fetch multiple different images concurrently always give me corrupted images.

Comment: Hmm i've tried to encode this photos in base 64 format and then decode in utf-8 format and that worked. i'll add answer to this question, so you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import base64

user_dynamic_response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-a')
user_amount_response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-b')
kp_month_response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-c')
kp_week_response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/send-data-d')

user_dynamic_image_data = base64.b64encode(user_dynamic_response.content).decode('utf-8')
user_amount_image_data = base64.b64encode(user_amount_response.content).decode('utf-8')
kp_month_image_data = base64.b64encode(kp_month_response.content).decode('utf-8')
kp_week_image_data = base64.b64encode(kp_week_response.content).decode('utf-8')

return render_template('second.html',
                       user_dynamic=user_dynamic_image_data,
                       user_amount=user_amount_image_data,
                       kp_month=kp_month_image_data,
                       kp_week=kp_week_image_data)
```

so uh this code solved the problem